# Vue config for multiple html files

Tags: vue.js

By default Vue will build `src/main.js` and inject build script to `public/index.html`.

Is there any way to support for multiple html files?

Example: I have `public/index.html` and `public/not-support.html` and I also have 2 script files for each html, `src/main.js` for and `src/not-support.js` for `public/not-support.html`

After building, we will have `dist/index.html` and `dist/not-support.html` with separate script file injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use vue-cli, you can set config in vue.config.js file to support for multiple html files:

```
 const config = {
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
    pages: {
        index: {
            entry: 'src/index.js',
            template: 'public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
        },
        support: {
            entry: 'src/support.js',
            template: 'public/support.html',
            filename: 'support.html',
        },
    },
    // ...config code
}
module.exports = config
```

refer to [link](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages), Build the app in multi-page mode

thanks.